# How can I create LaTeX diagrams in WordPress?

Tags: latex

I am writing a math blog in WordPress. I would like to include commutative diagrams and other simple diagrams in my blog. Which diagram library in LaTeX is available in WordPress? I am new to WordPress, and my site is hosted, so I'm not sure how to add plugins to a hosted site, so I'm looking for what is built-in to WordPress.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. This is not a buitlin feature and must therefore be added via 3rd party plugins. I'm afraid plugin recommendations are off-topic here on this site, according to [help/on-topic]. But it's of course possible to add images into the content editor, but I'm not sure if you need help with that?

Answer (score 1):

The Wordpress-produced plugin Jetpack has LaTeX support. See this [link](https://jetpack.com/support/beautiful-math-with-latex/). However, in my development, it didn't seem to work, so I've been using a plugin called MathJax-LaTeX. Yesterday, I discovered a plugin called WP QuickLaTeX, but I haven't been able to test it yet. Hope this helps.

Comment: For reference: http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/quicklatex/

Comment: MathJax is *not* LaTeX even if it seems to have the same syntax. This is why MathJax questions are off-topic on [tex.se] ;)

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you can do this quite easily via https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-latex/ (caveat - although I'm familiar with LaTeX, I haven't personally used this). You can set up an image generation server locally or use WordPress's own.

Comment: WordPress is hosting my blog. How do I add a plugin to a blog WordPress is hosting?

Comment: OK. I don't have a wordpress hosted account to check, but they claim here that it's supported natively: https://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/  - did this not work for you or did you not have a chance to try it yet?